# System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>.Model.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am trying to create my first ASP.NET MVC application but since two days I cannot solve my problem.

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach. I want to create DropDownListFor but there is always this error:

> System.NullReferenceException
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

My Model:

```
public class Animals
    {
        public int AnimalsId { get; set; }
        public int ClientsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TypesId { get; set; }
        public float Age { get; set; }
        public float Weight { get; set; }

        public virtual Types Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Clients> ClientsList { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookVisit> AnimalsVisits { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AnimalsId, ClientsId, Name, TypesId, Age, Weight")] Animals animals)
        {
            var person = new List<Clients>
            {
                new Clients { ClientsId = 50, Name = "Timo", Surname = "Werner", Email = "timo.werner@gmail.com", Phone = 123123123 }
            };

            var animalsView = new Animals
            {
                ClientsList = person.Select(x => new Clients
                {
                    ClientsId = x.ClientsId
                })
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Animals.Add(animals);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List", "Animal");
            }

            return View(animalsView);
        }
```

My view (only @model and dropdown):

```
@model xyz.Models.Animals    
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientsId, new SelectList(Model.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "Name", "Surname", "Email", "Phone"))
```

Could you please take a look ?

Comment: First of all, your `SelectList` call is wrong, Why are you passing all the property names to it ? Just pass one for the `value` and one for the `text`. `new SelectList(Model.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "Name")`

Comment: and How does your GET action method looks like? Are you passing a view model from that to the view ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I replaced dropdown to " @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientsId, new SelectList(Model.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "Name"))". 

My get method is:
    // GET: Animal
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
    return View();
    }

Comment: You need to pass an `Animals` object from your GET action method as your view code expects that

Comment: You mean something like this:
`// GET: Animal
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Animals testObj = new Animals();
            return View(testObj);
        }`

Comment: Yes .But you have to set the `ClientsList` property as your view code uses it

Comment: Could you please give sample code ? I don't get it. I would be grateful.

`// GET: Animal
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Animals testObj = new Animals();
            return View(testObj.ClientsList);
        }` I tried in this way but there is still the same error.

Comment: I posted an answer with sample code. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like you are not passing a valid view model object to the view. Your view code is expecting a valid model passed to it and the helper methods are using different properties of that.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     var clients = new List<Clients>
     {
           new Clients { ClientsId = 50, Name = "Timo" },
           new Clients { ClientsId = 51, Name = "Microsoft" }
     };

     var vm = new Animals
     {
         ClientsList = clients
     };
     return View(vm);
}
```

Also your current code which calls the `DropDownListFor` is wrong. When you create a `SelectList` from a collection, you have to pass the dataValue field and dataText fields.

```
@model Animals
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientsId,
                              new SelectList(Model.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may also be caused by trying to use a null model in razor view. In such  case check if the model is null or not before using it as shown below:

```
@if (Model != null) { 
    <a onclick="get('@Url.Action("GetEmployee", "DemoController")', @Model.Id)" ></a>
}
```